# How to use Safetynet recaptcha api in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, recaptcha

I am developing an android application and I want to include recaptcha in my app. But I do not understand how to use it. Can you help me so that I can us it in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this official [Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha) and implement with the steps provided.

Answer (score 0):

As Sneh referred to, first check out the Android Documentation. What could also be helpful would be to refer to [tutorial articles](https://medium.com/quick-code/using-googles-safetynet-recaptcha-api-with-android-48e2cf12f370) and [Sample Apps](https://github.com/sumitsahoo/reCAPTCHADemo) on Github.